# Why can't enum and record be combined?

Tags: java, enums, java-record

Recently I was just creating another enum type. I took advantage of the fact that in Java, an enum is a special type of class (and not a [named integer constant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/enum), like in C#). I made it with two fields, an all-arg constructor and getters for both fields.

This is an example:

```java
enum NamedIdentity {

    JOHN(1, "John the Slayer"),
    JILL(2, "Jill the Archeress");

    int id;
    String nickname;

    NamedIdentity(int id, String nickname) {
        this.id = id;
        this.nickname = nickname;
    }

    id id() {
        return this.id;
    }

    String nickname() {
        return this.nickname;
    }
}
```

Then I thought that Java 14's `record` keyword would have saved me the boilerplate code that this feature [was trying to save](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/359) me. This, as far as I know, doesn't combine with `enum`s. If *enum record*s would have existed, the abovementioned code would then look like this:

```java
enum record NamedIdentity(int id, String nickname) {
    JOHN(1, "John the Slayer"),
    JILL(2, "Jill the Archeress");
}
```

My question is: is there a reason that *enum records* don't exist? I could imagine several reasons, including, but not limited to:

- The number of use-cases for this feature would be too small, the Java language would benefit more if we, as Java language designers, designed and implemented other features.
- This is hard to implement, due to the internal implementation of the enum type.
- We, as Java language designers, simply didn't think about this, or we have not received such a request from the community yet, so we didn't prioritize it.
- This feature would have semantical issues, or the implementation of this feature could cause semantic ambiguity or otherwise confusion.

Comment: Should `NamedIdentity` implicitly extend `java.lang.Enum` or `java.lang.Record` then?

Comment: records are not about boilerplate reduction. In fact, one property of such an record is that the following code returns true: `original.equals(new NamedIdentitiy(original.id(), original.nickname()))`. As enums don't have public constructors, this code can't work.

Comment: Why use an enum when you can just define `NamedIdentity` as a record and declare `static final NamedIdentity` fields where you need them?

Comment: @ayane Because you can switch over enums.

Comment: @sp00m That's a *technical implementation* of the record concept. The language designers could have done something else if they really wanted enums and records to be combined. They could have made `Record` an interface, for instance. Hence some possible reasons at the bottom.

Comment: I can promise you the answer is NOT "we didn't think about this."

Answer (score 29, accepted):

## tl;dr

- Technical limitation: Multiple inheritance prevents mixing `Enum` with `Record` superclasses.
- Workaround: Keep a `record` as member field of your enum

```java
NamedIdentity.JILL.detail.nickname()  // ➣ "Jill the Archeress"
```

## Multiple inheritance

You asked:

> is there a reason that enum records don't exist?

The technical reason is that in Java, every enum is implicitly a subclass of [`Enum`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Enum.html) class while every record is implicitly a subclass of [`Record`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Record.html) class.

Java does not support multiple inheritance. So the two cannot be combined.

Perhaps a workaround could have been devised. The Java team considered a feature to be able to combine enum with record, but decided against it for whatever reasons. See [Comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65995692/why-cant-enum-and-record-be-combined/65998549#comment124302508_65995692) by [Brian Goetz](https://www.linkedin.com/in/briangoetz), the *Java Language Architect* at Oracle.

## Semantics

But more important is the semantics.

An enum is for declaring at compile time a limited set of named instances. Each of the enum objects is instantiated when the enum class loads. At runtime, we cannot instantiate any more objects of that class (well, maybe with extreme reflection/introspection code, but I’ll ignore that).

A record in Java is not automatically instantiated. Your code instantiated as many objects of that class as you want, by calling `new`. So not at all the same.

## Boilerplate reduction is *not* the goal of `record`

You said:

> I thought that Java 14's record keyword would have saved me the boilerplate code

You misunderstand the purpose of `record` feature. I suggest you read [JEP 395](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395), and watch the latest presentation by Brian Goetz on the subject.

As [commented by Johannes Kuhn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65995692/why-cant-enum-and-record-be-combined/65998549#comment116684242_65995692), the goal of `record` is *not* to reduce boilerplate. Such reduction is a pleasant side-effect, but is not the reason for the invention of `record`.

A record is meant to be a “nominal tuple” in formal terms.

- *Tuple* means a collection of values of various types laid out in a certain order, or as Wikipedia says: “finite ordered list (sequence) of elements”.
- *Nominal* means the elements each have a name.

A record is meant to be a simple and **transparent data carrier**. *Transparent* means all its member fields are exposed. It’s getter methods are simply named the same as the field, without using the `get…` convention of JavaBeans. The default implantation of `hashCode` and `equals` is to inspect each and every member field. The intention for a record is to focus on the data being carried, not behavior (methods).

Furthermore, a record is meant to be **shallowly immutable**. *Immutable* means you cannot change the primitive values, nor can you change the object references, in an instance of a record. The objects within a record instance may be mutable themselves, which is what we mean by *shallowly*. But values of the record’s own fields, either primitive values or object references, cannot be changed. You cannot re-assign a substitute object as one of the record’s member fields.

- When you have a limited set of instances known at compile time, use `enum`.
- When you are writing a class whose primary job is to immutably and transparently carry a group of data fields, use `record`.

## Worthy question

I can see where the two concepts could intersect, where at compile time we know of a limited set of immutable transparent collections of named values. So your question is valid, but not because of boilerplate reduction. [Brian Goetz said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65995692/why-cant-enum-and-record-be-combined/65998549#comment124302508_65995692) the Java team did indeed consider this idea.

## Workaround: Store a `record` on your `enum`

The workaround is quite simple: **Keep a `record` instance on your enum.**

You could pass a record to your enum constructor, and store that record as a member field on the enum definition.

Make the member field `final`. That makes our enum [immutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). So, no need to mark private, and no need to add a getter method.

First, the `record` definition.

```java
package org.example;

public record Performer(int id , String nickname)
{
}
```

Next, we pass an instance of `record` to the enum constructor.

```java
package org.example;

public enum NamedIdentity
{
    JOHN( new Performer( 1 , "John the Slayer" ) ),
    JILL( new Performer( 2 , "Jill the Archeress" ) );

    final Performer performer;

    NamedIdentity ( final Performer performer ) { this.performer = performer; }
}
```

If the `record` only makes sense within the context of the enum, we can nest the two together rather than have separate `.java` files. The `record` feature was built with nesting in mind, and works well there.

Naming the nested `record` might be tricky in some cases. I imagine something like `Detail` might do as a plain generic label if no better name is obvious.

```java
package org.example;

public enum NamedIdentity
{
    JOHN( new Performer( 1 , "John the Slayer" ) ),
    JILL( new Performer( 2 , "Jill the Archeress" ) );

    final Performer performer;

    NamedIdentity ( final Performer performer ) { this.performer = performer; }

    public record Performer(int id , String nickname) {}
}
```

To my mind, this workaround is a solid solution. We get clarity in the code with the bonus of reducing boilerplate. I like this as a general replacement for keeping a bunch of data fields on the enum, as using a `record` makes the intention explicit and obvious. I expect to use this in my future work, thanks to your Question.

Let's exercise that code.

```java
for ( NamedIdentity namedIdentity : NamedIdentity.values() )
{
    System.out.println( "---------------------" );
    System.out.println( "enum name: " + namedIdentity.name() );
    System.out.println( "id: " + namedIdentity.performer.id() );
    System.out.println( "nickname: " + namedIdentity.performer.nickname() );
}
System.out.println( "---------------------" );
```

When run.

```
---------------------
enum name: JOHN
id: 1
nickname: John the Slayer
---------------------
enum name: JILL
id: 2
nickname: Jill the Archeress
---------------------
```

## Declare locally

FYI, now in Java 16+, we can declare enums, records, and interfaces locally. This came about as part of the work done to create the records feature. See [*JEP 395: Records*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395).

So enums, records, and interfaces can be declared at any of three levels:

- In their own `.java.` file.
- Nested within a class.
- Locally, within a method.

I mention this in passing, not directly relevant to this Question.

Comment: A perfect answer, I argee with all points completely, including the suggested solution.
But still it would be actually interesting to see an `enum record` syntax in future versions of java. Which of course could in fact under the hood be just a syntactic sugar over your suggested solution – a nested record class, with java complier generating both the constructor and acessor methods, all of them delegating to the "invisible" private record field. So that we don't have to do `new Details(` at each item, or access `.details` manually everywhere.

Comment: Regarding the point of multiple inheritance — I think it's not a strong argument to say "they can't exist because multiple inheritance is not possible in Java". If they really wanted to allow enums and records to be combined, they could have walked another path, instead of extending from some superclass. I see, for instance, not a real reason of why the `Record` type should not an *interface*.

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you connect Lombok? The extra code that you want to remove will disappear with the annotations @AllArgsConstructor and @Getters